# Find the longest sequence in a List<int>

Tags: c#, algorithm, sequences

I have the following list:

```
List<int> days = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 24, 25, 26, 30 };
```

I want to get the start and end numbers of the longest sequence. For the above example I should get the (4, 8). If two sequences are available with the same length, I want the first one.

Note: the list will always have numbers in an increasing order.

so far I have tried this:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> seqs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
int _start = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= days.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        _start = days[i];
        continue;
    }

    if (i < days.Count)
    {
        if (days[i] == days[i - 1] + 1)
            continue;
        else
        {
            seqs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(_start, days[i - 1]));
            _start = days[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        seqs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(_start, days[i - 1]));
    }
}

var largestSeq = seqs
      .OrderByDescending(s => s.Item2 - s.Item1)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: He wants to find the longest sequence of numbers, In his example the longest sequence of consecutive numbers is 4/5/6/7/8

Comment: You really don't need a list of sequences. All you need is the starting point and length of the longest sequence found so far, and the start of the *current* sequence. When the current sequence ends, you compare it against the longest found so far, and update if required.

Comment: @JimMischel true, working on that now :) thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JimMischel gave direction to the optimal approach, but at very least you should not sort (`O(n log n)` ) to just get min or max value (`O(n)`)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: True, that. Especially when there's a `Min` method . . .

Answer (score 3):

this solution is shorter but uses a side effect, so it cannot be parallelized:

```
var days = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 24, 25, 26, 30 };

var groupNumber = 0;
var longestGroup = days
    .Select((x, i) => new
                        {
                            Item = x,
                            Index = i
                        })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index == 0 || x.Item - days[x.Index - 1] == 1
        ? groupNumber :
        ++groupNumber)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
    .First()
    .Select(x => x.Item)
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(longestGroup.First()+", "+longestGroup.Last());
```

output:

```
4, 8
```

this version does not use a side effect:

```
var days = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 24, 25, 26, 30 };

var groupEnds = days
    .Select((x, i) => new
    {
        Item = x,
        Index = i
    })
    .Where(x => x.Index > 0)
    .Where(x => x.Item - days[x.Index - 1] > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .Concat(new[]{days.Count})
    .ToArray();

var groupBounds =
    new[]{new{First=0,Last=groupEnds[0]-1}}
    .Concat(groupEnds
        .Select((x,i) => new{Item=x,Index=i})
        .Where(x => x.Index > 0)
        .Select(x => new{First=groupEnds[x.Index-1],Last=x.Item-1})
        )
    .ToArray();

var longestGroup = groupBounds
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Last - x.First)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine(days[longestGroup.First] + ", " + days[longestGroup.Last]);
```

output:

```
4, 8
```

Answer (score 2):

My version, which looks pretty similar to to @Gurgadurgen's.

```
List<int> days = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 24, 25, 26, 30 };           

int longestSequenceLength = 0;
int startIndexOfLongestSequence = 0;
int currentSequenceLength = 0;
int currentStartSequenceIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < days.Count; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || days[i] != days[i - 1] + 1) {
        currentSequenceLength = 1;
        currentStartSequenceIndex = i;
    }
    else {
        currentSequenceLength++;
    }

    if (currentSequenceLength > longestSequenceLength) {
        longestSequenceLength = currentSequenceLength;
        startIndexOfLongestSequence = currentStartSequenceIndex;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",days.Skip(startIndexOfLongestSequence)
   .Take(longestSequenceLength)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int longestSeqStart = days[0];
int longestSeqEnd = days[0];
int curSeqStart = days[0];
int curSeqEnd = days[0];
int lastVal = days[0];
for(int i = 1; i < days.Count(); i++)
{
    if(days[i] == lastVal + 1)
    {
        curSeqEnd = days[i];
        if(curSeqEnd - curSeqStart > longestSeqEnd - longestSeqStart )
        {
            longestSeqStart = curSeqStart;
            longestSeqEnd = curSeqEnd;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        curSeqStart = curSeqEnd = days[i];
    }
    lastVal = days[i];
}
```

Haven't tested it, but I've stared at it for a good five minutes, and it seems pretty sound.  I'll go run some tests in ideone and come back to edit them in :P

[EDIT] Tested it, and it indeed works.  For a list of integers, "days"

```
{1,2,3,4,5,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,2,3,4,5}
```

It spits out 12-18, which is the proper answer.
I'll just post the [Ideone link here](http://ideone.com/8g3aq3).

[EDIT 2] Note that this is scarcely optimized, and could (and should) be rendered down further before use in actual code.  For example, I realized only after writing this up that "lastVal" isn't actually even needed, as we can just check the value of "days" at the last index (i-1).

This should only serve as a logical basis for which to solve the problem you have, here.  Not as a final solution.